# how can select from drop down menu and call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down which has many options. I want that when I select any
option then it calls a function through JavaScript.

the code which I used is here

```
<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)"> <--- this is function in .js
<option value="daily">daily</option>
<option value="monthly">monthly</option>
</select>
```

I want when I select daily then function(daily) is invoked
and vice versa.

```
function report(daily)<-- js function {  
  loadXMLDoc('script/d_report.php','responseTag');
  document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden'; 
} 
function report(monthly) {
  document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';
  loadXMLDoc('script/m_report.php','responseTag');
  document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

Comment: where is your code? where are the functions?

Comment: <select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)">

<option value="daily">daily</option>
<option value="monthly">monthly</option>

</select>

Comment: function report(daily)<-- js function
 {

 
  
 loadXMLDoc('script/d_report.php','responseTag');
   document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden';
 }
 function report(monthly)
 {
 

document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';

 loadXMLDoc('script/m_report.php','responseTag');
  document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden';
  
 }

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)"> 
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="daily">daily</option>
  <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
</select>
```

using

```
function report(period) {
  if (period=="") return; // please select - possibly you want something else here

  const report = "script/"+((period == "daily")?"d":"m")+"_report.php";
  loadXMLDoc(report,'responseTag');
  document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden'; 
}
```

---

Unobtrusive version:

```
<select id="aa" name="aa"> 
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="daily">daily</option>
  <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
</select>
```

using

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("aa").addEventListener("change",function() {
    const period = this.value;
    if (period=="") return; // please select - possibly you want something else here

    const report = "script/"+((period == "daily")?"d":"m")+"_report.php";
    loadXMLDoc(report,'responseTag');
    document.getElementById('responseTag').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('list_report').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('formTag').style.visibility='hidden'; 
  }); 
});
```

---

jQuery version - same select with ID

```
$(function() {
  $("#aa").on("change",function() {
    const period = this.value;
    if (period=="") return; // please select - possibly you want something else here

    var report = "script/"+((period == "daily")?"d":"m")+"_report.php";
    loadXMLDoc(report,'responseTag');
    $('#responseTag').show();
    $('#list_report').hide();
    $('#formTag').hide(); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Greetings 
if i get you right you need a JavaScript function that doing it

```
function report(v) {
//To Do
  switch(v) {
    case "daily":
      //Do something
      break;
    case "monthly":
      //Do somthing
      break;
    }
  }
```

Regards

Comment: i dont get u do u mean u need to enter it daily as enumeration not in "daily" ??

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function report(func)
{
    func();
}

function daily()
{
    alert('daily');
}

function monthly()
{
    alert('monthly');
}
</script>
```

Comment: The difference is which report to show. Why have multiple functions when all you need is a simple choice