# how can i call different function by change dropdown menu option

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

***this is my code***

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form  name="form2">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<b>From Date</b>:</td><td><input type="text" id="from_date" readonly="true" name="f_date"><a href="javascript: show_cal('document.form2.f_date.value')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
<td><b>To Date:</td><td></b><input type="text" id="to_date" readonly="true" name="t_date"><a href="javascript: show_cal('document.form2.t_date.value')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
<td><b>Vehicle Number</b>:</td><td><input type="text" id="vhc_number">
<td><input type="button" value="show report" onclick="show_record_monthly()" style="background-color:#E6E6DC"></td>
<td>
<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)"> 
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="da">daily</option>
<option value="mo">monthly</option>
<select>
```

**

i want to do it that when i select option from dropdownmenu **monthly** and fill form when i click on button it will run monthly function which take all values**(from date ,to date,vehicle number)** from form 
but when i select **daily** from dropdownmenu it will take only **(from date)** value
and when i click on button it run daily function.

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you already have some php code?

Comment: First of all, where is your javascript code? Second of all, I have no idea what you mean. Can you be more clear?

Comment: this is abit ambiguous, show us the js function

Comment: Can you first finish this one - and perhaps tell us why you ask another question which is as far as I can see identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323375/how-can-select-from-drop-down-menu-and-call-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

It requires to submit your form with appropriate parameters, that is the only way to call a server side function. You can use Ajax to make it interactive. Hint: Use `onchange()` event and `selectedIndex` property of `<select>`. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean processing the form in php?

```
switch ($_POST['aa']) {
  case 'da' : daily($_POST['from_date']); break;
  case 'mo' : monthly($_POST['from_date'], $_POST['to_date'],$_POST['vehicle_number']); break;
  default : echo "Please select a value from the drop-down menu";
}
```

This of course only if you add `method="POST"` to your `form`.

Comment: i was writing the exact same answer, but then realized i think he wants the "javascript" to call this result

Comment: javascript is a better choice here. He needs to make some of the form elements hidden or disabled on change of the combobox.

Comment: in javascript.from where i call php to select data and run different queries on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function switch in Javascript, then do this:

```
<script>
    dropdown_func = {
        daily: report_daily,       // these are the functions
        monthly: report_monthly    // they should already be defined
    }
<script>
```

Which can then be invoked in the dropdown with:

```
<select name="aa" onchange="drowpdown_func[this.value]()">
```