# How to apply onblur event on dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to fire some javascript function when my focus is off from dropdown list.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're looking for a jquery solution since you have jquery in your tag? You may refer to the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) on .blur()

Answer (score 1):

you need to attach `onblur` event on the client side with some javascript

```
  $("mydropdown").blur(function(){

    // here goes your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work like this for instance:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Kfch/2/

What usualy is better is to trigger on select that can be done using jQuery librarfy to javascript. Here is an example.

[how can select from drop down menu and call javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323375/how-can-select-from-drop-down-menu-and-call-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise something like

```
      $("body").delegate("#sliderSelect", "change", function(){})
```

otherwise even if you didn't change your selection the event would trigger on focus. Delegate also allows for a more dynamic dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#DropDownListID").on("blur", function(){

// Your code

});
```