# using ajax for deleting from dropdown

Tags: ajax

I am trying to delete values from the dropdown by using ajax and php. Here is my code:

```
    function d1()
                    {
                      var m=document.getElementById('team').value;

                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                }
                            }
                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "k2.php?q=" +m, true);
                            xmlhttp.send();

                          }
                    }

                    </script>
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
                          <div class="jumbotron">
                            <fieldset>
            <legend class="center-block"><b>Select Team Name</b></legend>
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                  <div class="form-group">
            <select name='team'  class='form-control input-sm' id='team'>;
                                        <?php
                                             $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','yomahesh9094') or die("connection failed");
                                        $db=mysql_select_db('buzzer',$conn)or die("could not select database");
                                        $n=mysql_query("select * from quiz");

                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($n)){
                                          echo "<option value='{$row['TeamName']}'>{$row['TeamName']}</option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";
                                      ?>


                                           </div>
```

Delete

I have tried to issue an alert to see if my Javascript/ajax code is working. But no output is being shown.Can u tell what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call d1() in your script so it won't get executed. You have to bind it to the select event of #team.
You can do that [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/select/)  or [plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323626/3653756) but first solution is a bit more forward.