# Getting different types of html output based on a menu selection

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I am trying to based on a menu select either get a textbox or another drop down menu.  I have been able to do this via javascript functions. Now I got some help from this website:

[how can select from drop down menu and call javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323375/how-can-select-from-drop-down-menu-and-call-javascript-function)

but this only took me part of the way toward my goal.  For instance was trying to display some html funciton based on selecting "daily" in the menu choice but alas this did not work.  Below is my code, can you please help me tweak this code so I can get the html code embedded in the javascript to display upon selecting daily in the drop down menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)"> 
 <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="daily">daily</option>
  <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
   </select>
<script>
function report(v) {
//To Do
    switch(v) {
        case "daily":
            notification_var = "<hr>";
            notification_var += "<table width=100% border=0>";
            notification_var += "<tr>";
            notification_var += "<td align=left  width=30% style='align:left;padding-left:0px;height:30px;'><span id='toplink_daily_remarks'></span></td>";
            notification_var += "<td align=center><label style='font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;color:#000080;'>Daily Info and    Remarks</label></td>";
            notification_var += "<td width=30%>&nbsp;</td>";
            notification_var += "</tr>";
            notification_var += "</table>";
            return notification_var;
        break;
    case "monthly":
        //Do somthing
        break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defined where you are going to inject the markup. See my working example of how to do this.

```js
var reportWrapper = document.getElementById('reportWrapper');
  
function report(v) {
  switch (v) {
    case "daily":
   daily();
      break;
    case "monthly":
      monthly();
      break;
  }
}

function daily() {  
  var notification_var = "<hr>";
  notification_var += "<table width=100% border=0>";
  notification_var += "<tr>";
  notification_var += "<td align=left  width=30% style='align:left;padding-left:0px;height:30px;'><span id='toplink_daily_remarks'></span></td>";
  notification_var += "<td align=center><label style='font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;color:#000080;'>Daily Info and    Remarks</label></td>";
  notification_var += "<td width=30%>&nbsp;</td>";
  notification_var += "</tr>";
  notification_var += "</table>";
  
  reportWrapper.innerHTML = notification_var;
}

function monthly () {
  reportWrapper.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="daily">daily</option>
  <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
</select>

<div id="reportWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: I tried running the above code and would get the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.  How do I resolve this?"

Comment: @jms1980 have you updated the html to include `<div id="reportWrapper"></div>`? Do you have  this line at the top of your js `var reportWrapper = document.getElementById('reportWrapper');`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you ask "How to insert my HTML code on page upon selection of certain value".
I tweaked your code by three lines, and it seems to be working. Is this what you were expecting?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="aa" onchange="report(this.value)"> 
 <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="daily">daily</option>
  <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
   </select>
<script>
function report(v) {
//To Do
    switch(v) {
        case "daily":
            var notification_var = "<hr>";
            notification_var += "<table width=100% border=0>";
            notification_var += "<tr>";
            notification_var += "<td align=left  width=30% style='align:left;padding-left:0px;height:30px;'><span id='toplink_daily_remarks'></span></td>";
            notification_var += "<td align=center><label style='font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;color:#000080;'>Daily Info and    Remarks</label></td>";
            notification_var += "<td width=30%>&nbsp;</td>";
            notification_var += "</tr>";
            notification_var += "</table>";
            document.open();
            document.write(notification_var);
            document.close();
            return notification_var;
        break;
    case "monthly":
        //Do somthing
        break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```