# Set values to render grid depending on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

Im trying to set values to render a grid depending on selected option in a select box. so far I could make an if scentence. Im not very sure if what Im doing is "right" but it is not working... (so I guess not)

```
search: function () {
    console.time("products.renderResult()");
    var instance = this, 
    pr = "&VISIBLETOALL=1",
    al = this.getValue("AllianceUNID"), 
    pa = this.getValue("PartnerUNID"), 
    qryStr = "&ALUNID=" + al + "&PAUNID=" + pa, 
    //urlVTA = session.getPath("main") + "agtGetProducts?OpenAgent" + pr + qryStr,
    url = session.getPath("main") + "agtGetProducts?OpenAgent";
    $('select[name=productSelect]').on('change', function () {
        var value = $('select[name=productSelect]').val();
        if (value == 'VISIBLE_TO_ALL') {
            return url + pr + qryStr;
        } else {
            return url + qryStr;
        }
    });

    $.getJSON(url).done(function (products) {
        if (products.errormessage) {.....
```

So this is my search function which should return url + variables depending on `if value = VISIBLE_TO_ALL` (should set value url + pr + qryStr) else will show only url + qryStr

So my problem is here I think

```
$('select[name=productSelect]').on('change', function () {
    var value = $('select[name=productSelect]').val();
    if (value == 'VISIBLE_TO_ALL') {
        return url + pr + qryStr;
    } else {
        return url + qryStr;
    }
});
```

My html

```
<select name="productSelect">
    <option value="">-
    <optgroup label="Products">
        <option value="ALL">All products
        <option value="VISIBLE_TO_ALL">Products visible to all
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Alliances"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Partners"></optgroup>
</select>
```

Is this possible to do? or how should I set the variables?

Comment: This question has be asked and solved before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5323375/6620283). You will just need to adapt function to fit in with the provided solution.

Comment: I was in that solution but it doesnt apply my issue... :(

Comment: can you provide the HTML code for your selectbox as well ?

Comment: I updated my question :)

Comment: actually I think the function is working, just that you have nothing catching the returned values. Try printing the values to the console to see if they are the correct ones

Comment: mmm, I get the right values when I print them in the console...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181475/discussion-between-casualcoder-and-fernando-lopez).

Answer (score 0):

Given your response that you get the right responses when you print out the values, that means that the function is working properly and there are no issues with it. Instead of returning the values (which does not help you as you are not storing or using the returned values), you should instead directly use those values as you wish from this function itself.

Since you wanted to fill a grid using these values you can do that from this function itself using jQuery, and your grid should be updated to reflect the appropriate values whenever a new selection is made from your select box